# Масштабирование страниц сайта

Tags: media-queries, viewport

Как сделать масштабирование сайта, за условии что header и footer меняются отдельно, обычными медиа?

Comment: Сделай отдельные `footer.css` и `header.css`, где напиши все правила `@media` только для них. В чем проблема?

Comment: А другие блоки viewport , и все будет работать?

Comment: Если так переживаешь, то используй обращение к элементам через селектор `header` а для футера через `footer` тогда они ничего другого не затронут.

Comment: Так а можно использовать viewport конкретно к конкретной секции, а не ко всей странице?

Comment: Конечно можно. Просто напиши `@media` для главного контента страницы, и не используй в нем селекторы для header и footer